# MikTex update wizard not working

Tags: miktex, miktex-update

I'm trying to install some packages in Miktex, but I get an error that my repository is outdated. So then try to run the Miktex update wizard and get this error.

[image: Miktex update wizard not working]

I tried to find similar errors, but I have not been able to find any solution regarding this matter.

Comment: Did you synchronise  the repository with MiKTeX Package Manager?

Comment: Don't start the update manager from the menu in the package manager. Open it directly (there should be an entry in the startmenu, if not search for miktex-update_admin.exe and miktex-update.exe).

Comment: It didn't work. I reinstalled MikTeX, and used my old respository, but now it says "get proxy host by name failed in tcp_connect()". I've tried deleting "http://" from the address, but that doesn't work either